# SQL условие, если нет записей, то продолжить

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
$query
        ->join("black_list", function($join) use ($User) {
            $join->on("black_list.id_user", "=", "post.id_user")
                ->where("black_list.id_black", "=", $User['id']);
        })
        ->havingRaw("COUNT(black_list.id_black) = ?", [0]);
```

Пытаюсь собрать логику: если в black_list ничего не находит, то все ок и продолжаем дальше
Проблема в том, что не отдает записи, ошибок тоже не отдает, где тут проблема? Почему не работает?

Comment: Посмотрите логи :-) Если это ларавел, то первый вопрос должен звучать - где у ларавела логи.

Comment: @Чад да там нет ошибки, отдает count = 0, просто не отдает никаких записей... Где-то в логике кода ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `join` на `leftJoin`

Comment: @Knyaz71 сработало, только выдает всего 1 запись, хотя их 15 должно быть, limit не стоит

Comment: По текущим данным сложно сказать, поэтому поразмышляю... (1) Вместо `first()` используйте `get()`. (2) Возможно, стоит убрать `where` из `join`.

Comment: стоит get(),  а если убрать where, то логика нарушиться, если выкидываю за join, то тоже самое получается

Comment: @Knyaz71 добавил `->groupBy("post.id")` и заработало